# Bunch of elements in array Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I need some help to count bunches of adjacent elements in arrays.

Lets say I have 4 integer arrays.

```
myArray = {1, 1, 1, 1}
myArray2 = {5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 1, 10, 11, 12};
myArray3 = {5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 12};
myArray4 = {5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12};
```

I want to calculate the bunch number of elements in these arrays.

Desired output should be:

```
myArray => 1 (1 bunch of adjacent element "1")
myArray2 => 0 (no adjacent element)
myArray3 => 1 (1 bunch of adjacent  element "7")
myArray4 => 2 (2 bunches of adjacent elements "7" and "11")
```

I can count the adjacent elements but not the bunches.

Here are the code I wrote:

```
import acm.program.ConsoleProgram;

public class project extends ConsoleProgram{
    public void run ()
    {
        int[] myArray = {1, 1, 1, 1};
        int[] myArray2 = {5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 1, 10, 11, 12};
        int[] myArray3 = {5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 12};
        int[] myArray4 = {5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12};        

        println("myArray -> " + countBunches(myArray));
        println("myArray2 -> " + countBunches(myArray2));
        println("myArray3 -> " + countBunches(myArray3));
    }

    public int countBunches(int[] myArray)
    {   
        int count = 0;
        int saveIndex;
        int saveContent;

        for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                saveContent = myArray[i];
            }
            else
            {
                saveContent = myArray[i-1];
                if(saveContent == myArray[i])
                {

                    saveContent = myArray[i];
                    saveIndex = i;
                    count++;
                    println(myArray[saveIndex] + " repatingb" + saveIndex + ". element");
                }
                else
                {
                    saveContent = myArray[i];
                }
            }
        }   

        return(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but "I want" is not a question, but code requirement. Please [edit] your question and include description of specific problem which is stopping you from writing your code. Also including your attempts may encourage others to help you.

Comment: @Pshemo i added my attempt. Sorry for "i want" typo.

Comment: @freedev I've been trying since today and SO is the latest station for me on that issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with and can you use collections like Set?

Comment: No i am not, actually i am not allowed to use collections like "Set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are counting each time an element matches the last one. So if you have 3 of the same items in a row, it counts as 2, instead of 1.

One way is to keep track of the last item and whether it was a match or not:

```
public int countBunches(int[] myArray)
{   
    int count = 0;
    int lastItem;
    boolean lastItemMatched;

    for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            lastItem = myArray[0];
            lastItemMatched = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(lastItem == myArray[i])
            {
                if(!lastItemMatched)
                {
                    count++;
                }

                lastItemMatched = true;
            } else {
                lastItemMatched = false;
            }

            lastItem = myArray[i];
        }
    }   

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, how could not i think this one. Thank you @Jason

Answer (score 1):

I do not want to make homework, but let's see.

What approach?

- You have a bunch count, and walk the array
- Either there is a bunch in progress or not
- If the current element is the prior element, then it depends on whether already bunch or not.

That is more or less your approach.

Alternatively you could also check at i whether it is the start of a bunch (inner loop) and  set i after the bunch.

Use clear variables:

```
   public int countBunches(int[] numbers)
```

Comment: Thank you for your efford, @Jason's solution is much more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice simple way:

```
private static int countBunches(int[] numbers){
    Integer previous = null;
    int bunch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (previous!=null){
            if (previous==numbers[i]){
                bunch++;
                while (i < numbers.length && previous==numbers[i++] ){} 
            }
        }
        if (i < numbers.length){
            previous = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return bunch;
}
```

In this method we keep track of the previous number (that's why I use Integer, to be able to determine whether there was a previous number and to rely on null).

One trick is to go through the entire sequence of equal numbers in an inner loop.

Comment: Thank you for your solution @David. This one looks more practical.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Don't forget to vote up and accept as answer